# Adding a CSS class to $('#gallery a').lightBox();

Tags: css, lightbox

My theme uses its own style for the light box and I have no clue how to add my themes class to the code below so it loads my lightbox themes.

The code is:

```
$(function() {
    $('#gallery a').lightBox();
});
```

How do I add my themes CSS class to this code? My themes CSS class is `TZ-lightbox`.

Comment: Which lightbox library are you using?

Comment: Its Just called jquery.lightbox.js think it is version 0.5

Comment: I think a part of your comment didn't come through. If you copy-pasted a line from the file, try putting it between two ` characters so you get something like `... line from the file...`

Comment: yeah copied the stuff from the top of the lightbox.js but this site said it wass to big to post, it was 100 charecters to long but the file says it's version 0.5

Answer (score 1):

By your description, something like this?
The `lightbox()` method returns the jQuery object with which you started, so just chain another jQuery method to it, the one that adds a class.

`$('#gallery a').lightBox().addClass("TZ-lightbox");`

Comment: ok that works but it opens the lightbox at the bottom of the page instead of in the midle. the black bit is also part of the lightbox instead of shadowing the screen out. I am thinking it maybe somthing to do with my theme using its own lightbox scripting. I will post the JS that my theme uses for the lightbox

Comment: Perhaps the class should be added to `<html>` instead.

Comment: Tried that but because the images wraped round a link it wont work